# EndpointNotFoundException with WCF client in same Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm hosting a WCF Service in my WPF app and want to consume it within the same assembly (in another instance, though). For the sake of dependency injection I'm calling `ServiceHost.Open` with an already created instance of my service implementation.

#### Contract and Service implementation

```
[ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign)]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    PartnerInfo GetPartnerInfo();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service : IService
{
    private IpService _ipService;

    public Service(IpService ipService)
    {
        _ipService = ipService;
    }

    public PartnerInfo GetPartnerInfo()
    {
        var info = new PartnerInfo();
        info.Address = _ipService.GetLocalIpAddress();

        return info;
    }
}
```

#### App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Project.WebService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="endpoint0"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService"
                  contract="Project.WebService.IService">
          <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="Project.WebService.Service"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:61000/Project/Service.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService"
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 sendTimeout="00:30:00"
                 receiveTimeout="infinite">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
          </security>
          <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="true" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint
        binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService"
        contract="Project.WebService.IService"
        name="NetTcpBinding_IService">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

#### ServiceHost creation

```
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(_Service);
_serviceHost.Open();
```

After opening the `ServiceHost`, it listens on Port 61000 (checked via netstat). Altough I don't need it (because I created a client implementing IService myself), I tested creating a service reference and it worked.

However, my service implementation looks like this:

```
public class ServiceClient : ClientBase<IService>, IService
{
    public ServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public PartnerInfo GetPartnerInfo()
    {
        return Channel.GetPartnerInfo();
    }
}
```

And when I'm calling it this way, with another service hosting instance on the same machine, an `EndpointNotFoundException` is thrown:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("net.tcp://<IPAdress>:61000");
Uri uri = new Uri(baseUri, "Project/Service.svc");

// Spn identity is only here for testing purposes, doesn't work either way
return new ServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IService", new EndpointAddress(uri, EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("NetTcpBinding_IService")));
```

Am I missing something on my implementation of the `ServiceClient` as I have both service and client in the same assembly and therefore don't want to create a service reference in Visual Studio?

### Update

I tested the whole process creating a Service Reference. This doesn't work either. I also double-checked my firewall rules. Here is the exception message:

`There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://192.168.200.29:61000/Project/Service.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.`

### Update 2

For testing purposes, I created a second `wsHttpBinding` Endpoint. This one is reachable in my browser, so the service is up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I solved the (quite simple) issue myself:

As it turned out, the service URL wasn't `net.tcp://localhost:61000/Project/Service.svc` but `net.tcp://localhost:61000/Project/Service.svc/endpoint0`.

After removing the "endpoint0" from my endpoint configuration, the connection went well:

```
<endpoint address=""
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService"
          contract="Project.WebService.IService">
  <!-- -->
</endpoint>
```